# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :

Tags: java, string

I have a `String = "abc model 123 abcd1862893007509396 abcd2862893007509404"`, if I provide space between `abcd1` & `number` eg. `abcd1 862893007509396` my code will work fine, but if there is no space like `abcd1862893007509396`, I will get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, please help ?:

PFB the code :

```
String text = "";
final String suppliedKeyword = "abc model 123 abcd1862893007509396 abcd2862893007509404";
String[] keywordarray = null;
String[] keywordarray2 = null;
String modelname = "";
String[] strIMEI = null;

if ( StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase( suppliedKeyword,"model")) {
    keywordarray = suppliedKeyword.split("(?i)model");

    if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(keywordarray[1], "abcd")) {
        keywordarray2 = keywordarray[1].split("(?i)abcd");
        modelname = keywordarray2[0].trim(); 

        if (keywordarray[1].trim().contains(" ")) {
            strIMEI = keywordarray[1].split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < strIMEI.length; i++) {
                if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(strIMEI[i],"abcd")) {
                    text = text + " " + strIMEI[i] + " "
                            + strIMEI[i + 1];
                    System.out.println(text);
                }
            }
        } else {
            text = keywordarray2[1];            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"please help"* - Please provide a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Please post the code that is throwing the exception

Comment: I have attached the dummy code

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code the only thing i can consider for cause of error is

```
if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(strIMEI[i],"abcd")) {
    text = text + " " + strIMEI[i] + " "
    + strIMEI[i + 1];
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

You are trying to access strIMEI[i+1] which will throw an error if your last element in strIMEI contains "abcd".

Comment: yes I know from where the error is coming ,need to change the code for same

Comment: @sparsh in that case you have to prevent that error by make sure that either lsat element in strIMEI should not contain abcd or by go up till strIMEI.length-1 in your loop

Comment: i dont know what is your aim behind accessing strIMEI[i] and strIMEI[i+1] at same time if you want this behavior without error there is one more thing you can do is add dummy data after keywordarray[1] after split and before "strIMEI = keywordarray[1].split(" ");"

Comment: if (keywordarray[1].trim().contains(" ")) {                                                          keywordarray[1]+=" dummytext";                                                                               strIMEI = keywordarray[1].split(" "); //and now it will allow you to go for                                 strIMEI[i+1]